# Fixing this "Sent Email on Due Date" Script?

Tags: excel, vba, email

Although I know absolutely nothing of VBA, I've read about a dozen topics on the subject on multiple communities in an attempt to figure out something, a way to do it.

I found the script that was the most likely to work in my case, analyzed it, switched the references, cells and so on. I think I am getting close to something functional, alas, I fear it is as far as my knowledge and Trials & Errors goes.

The script currently does nothing... E5 to E35 contains the due dates, the cell next to each of these cells contain the "Sent" and "Not Sent" value so it doesn't send duplicate emails.

This is in the sheet that it needs to run:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim FormulaCell     As Range
Dim FormulaRange    As Range
Dim NotSentMsg      As String
Dim MyMsg           As String
Dim SentMsg         As String
Dim MyLimit         As Double

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

'Above the MyLimit value it will triger the email
MyLimit = Today()

Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("E5:E35")

On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
        If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
            MyMsg = "Not numeric"
        Else
            If .Value > MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    strTO = "random@adress.com"
                    strCC = ""
                    strBCC = ""
                    strSub = "Greetings, " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value
                    strBody = "Hi Sir " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This email is to notify that you need to do your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Regards, Yourself"
                    If sendMail(strTO, strSub, strBody, strCC) = True Then MyMsg = SentMsg
'                        Call Mail_with_outlook2
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

Next FormulaCell


ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

And this is the module I use to send the emails:

```
Option Explicit

Public FormulaCell As Range
Public strTO       As String
Public strCC       As String
Public strBCC      As String
Public strSub      As String
Public strBody     As String
Public strAttach   As String

Public Function sendMail(strTO As String, strSub As String, strBody As String, Optional strCC As String, Optional strBCC As String, Optional strAttach As String) As Boolean
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error GoTo errorMail
With OutMail
    .To = strTO
    If Len(Trim(strCC)) > 0 Then .CC = strCC
    If Len(Trim(strBCC)) > 0 Then .BCC = strBCC
    .Subject = strSub
    .Body = strBody

    If Len(Trim(strAttach)) > 0 Then
        If Dir(strAttach, vbNormal) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add (strAttach)
    End If
    .Send
End With
sendMail = True

exitFunction:
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Exit Function

errorMail:
MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description
GoTo exitFunction

End Function
```

Many thanks for any help given to this tremendous task!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! The script below appears to work properly with my document. Although it only sends email for tasks that still have time left! I would need the script to send an email only when the date is the same as "Today()" How do I do that?

Pretty sure it is something to do with the "My Limit = Date" line, but how do I change Date to include only the current day?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim FormulaCell          As Range
Dim FormulaRange    As Range
Dim NotSentMsg      As String
Dim MyMsg           As String
Dim SentMsg         As String
Dim MyLimit         As Double

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

'Above the MyLimit value it will triger the email
MyLimit = Date

Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("E5:E35")
On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
            If .Value > MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    strTO = "fmais@eox.com"
                    strCC = "fais@box.com"
                    strBCC = ""
                    strSub = "Greetings " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value
                    strBody = "Hi Sir, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This email is to notify that you need to do your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Regards, Yourself"
                    If sendMail(strTO, strSub, strBody, strCC) = True Then MyMsg = SentMsg
'                        Call Mail_with_outlook2
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

Next FormulaCell


ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: This is because you're checking only for dates that are "bigger" than "Today". Adapt the line "If .Value > MyLimit Then" to "If (.Value > MyLimit) or (.Value = MyLimit) Then". Or if you want only the tasks that have the due date today then "If (.Value = MyLimit) Then".

Comment: If you wanted you could also change the code, that if the due date is today you'll send the message that you already have and if the due date is some days from now (bigger than today) then you'll send a message like "This email is to notify that you need to do your task : " & TASK & vbNewLine & "Due Date : " & FormulaCell.Value & REST

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it :)

Comment: Everything working now as you wished to? :) No Problem, happy to help :) Can you mark it as answered, if everything is ok :)

Comment: Haha you deserve it for your time :P I personally doesn't know VBA. I'm more of a check, analyze and attempt kind of guy :) Your explanations helped me understand some of the basics. It is appreciated

Comment: That's how it started out for me as well, but as I am working quite intensively with vba these days I learned a lot of things already, but there are still a lot more things that I don't know or don't understand. So whenever I can help someone it's like a step forward for me as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following code by debugging step by step? If there is an error, press debug and comment which line gets what kind of error. I would love to know if this gets you closer to your destination.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() 

Dim FormulaCell As Range 
Dim FormulaRange As Range 
Dim NotSentMsg As String 
Dim MyMsg As String 
Dim SentMsg As String 
Dim MyLimit As Date

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

MyLimit = Date

Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("E5:E35")

'On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
        If (IsDate(.Value) = True) Then
            If (.Value > MyLimit) Then
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    strTO = "random@adress.com"
                    strCC = ""
                    strBCC = ""
                    strSub = "Greetings, " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value
                    strBody = "Hi Sir " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This email is to notify that you need to do your task : " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Regards, Yourself"
                    Call sendMail(strTO, strSub, strBody, strCC)
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

Next FormulaCell


'EndMacro:
'Application.EnableEvents = True

'MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
'     & vbLf & Err.Number _
'     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Sure thing :) First message I get is that the Sub or Function is not defined for the Today() in:
    MyLimit = Today()

Is there a way I can provide you with the sheet so you give it a look?

Comment: oooh I just didnt notice... the function Today() is returning a date and not a double, you'll have to declare it as Date, sorry I missed out on this, will correct it in my code

Comment: And I would love to give it a look, but as I am working on Mac this will not necessairily work, I'm sorry but you'll have to test yourself ^.^

Comment: also to get the date of today you'll have to use Date instead of Today(). Sorry.....

Comment: First and foremost, thanks for your support so far. It is really appreciated :)

Comment: For some reason, nothing happens when I compile the VBA project and attempt to run it...
It's unfortunate that you cannot check the sheet itself, so I took a screenshot of it. Maybe it will allow you to understand my setup some more and see a flaw in the script?

Comment: Check out: http://i.imgur.com/yvnKfGa.png . 
The Due Date, Notes and Task name automatically format themselves depending if the task is due Today, in a Few Days or is past due time.
I also have a few macros as stated in Task State Shortcuts to effortlessly switch the Task State to something else.